# error message while updating R version from 2.10 to 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: upgrade

I get the following error message while trying to update my current R version from 2.10 to 3.0.Any tips would be welcome.

Thanks

```
mgjohnson@mgjohnson-linux:~$ apt-get install r-base
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
mgjohnson@mgjohnson-linux:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run this as superuser by prefixing `sudo` to your command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

You can find more info here: http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/sudo.8.php which defines `sudo` as follows:

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified in the sudoers file. The real and effective uid and gid are set to match those of the target user as specified in the passwd file (the group vector is also initialized when the target user is not root).

Answer (score 0):

You should run `sudo apt-get install r-base`. `sudo` gives you the priviledges for installation.